# How to match a URL location dynamically in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I am new to nginx, I am trying to blocked a specific url that it will return 403.
I need to return 403 when the url is: http://mysite.domain.com/user/test.test/files/person.jpg?=download. However this url --> location /user/([a-zA-Z.]+.?$)/files/ does not work. Please help. :(

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    error_page 403 /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html/;
                internal;

    }

    location /test {
        return 502;
    }

    location /user/([a-zA-Z.]+\.?$)/files/ {
        return 403;
    }

    location /user/files/ {
        return 503;
    }

    location / {
        return 500;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have written a regular expression. You need to use the `~` or `~*` operator. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). Also, I don't understand the `\.?$` sequence. Try: `location ~ ^/user/([a-zA-Z.]+)/files/ { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you so much. You saved me :)  I hope you can comment this so I can mark it as an answer :) thank you.